# Participle clauses with multiple subjects

Tags: participles, participle-clauses

I was told that the following sentence was incorrect because the participle clause has a different subject:

**"When deciding punishments for crimes, criminals' intentions are important."**

If that's true, then is the following sentence, which I think sounds quite natural, also incorrect?

**"When creating a nutrition plan, age is an important factor."**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The subject of the main clause is not the subject of the participle there.

Answer (score 1):

The **when**-clause complements **are important** and **is an important factor** and could remain at the front of the sentence or be moved to the end of the sentence:

> Criminals' intentions are important when deciding punishments for
>   crimes.
>
> Age is an important factor when creating a nutrition plan.

Most native speakers would understand those **when**-clauses as a kind of impersonal construction, when **one** is deciding|creating. They would not parse the sentences so that **intentions** or **age** is the subject of the **when**-clause.

Comment: I think "when deciding punishments for crimes" is a participle adverb, and I am not sure if the OP's original sentence is actually wrong. I mean when it comes to participle adverbs, the only wrong construction comes to my mind is dangling participle which is not the case here. Am I right?

Comment: @Cardinal I find nothing wrong with the original construction. I would just say it's less common.